# Angular JS Form Calculation

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm new to angular.js, and I want to calculate form fields, I am able to calculate $scope.piece and output the results to the html. The problem is that I cannot calculate $scope.$scope.typeofwritings. How can I get the value of $scope.typeofwritings. like $scope.calculation = ($scope.piece * $scope.typeofwritings);

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('formExample', ['ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.typeofwritings = [{
   value: '5',
   text: 'Writing from scratch'
    }, {
   value: '3',
   text: 'Editing or Proofreading'
    }
    ];
    
$scope.pieces = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
$scope.piece = 1;

  $scope.calculate = function(){
  $scope.calculation = $scope.piece;
  
  }
  $scope.calculate();
    
 
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<tr>
      <td width="186"><label for="type_writing">Type of Writing:</label></td>
      <td width="269"><select ng-change="calculate()" ng-model="type_writing" ng-options="o.value as o.text for o in typeofwritings" ng-init="type_writing='5'" name="type_writing" id="type_writing">
      </select>
      </td>
</tr>

<tr>
      <td><label for="length">Article Length:</label></td>
      <td><select ng-model="length" ng-options="o.value as o.text for o in lengths" ng-init="length='1'" name="length" id="length">
      </select></td>
</tr>

<tr>     
      <td><strong>Order Cost</strong><div style="color:#D76D25; font-size:24px;">${{calculation}}</div></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: I'm not really following what you're trying to do.  What are you "calculating"?    What is `$scope.typewritings`?  Do you mean `$scope.typeofwritings`?  That's a complex object, how do you expect to be able to *multiply* by that?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. You would need a quantity for each item, not one scope count for all. Not clear at all what your `pieces` array is

Comment: yes I mean $scope.typeofwritings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a value in an array of object you can do as follows:

```
scope.calculation = ($scope.piece * $scope.typeofwritings[0].value); // 1*5
scope.calculation = ($scope.piece * $scope.typeofwritings[1].value);// 1*3
```

Comment: Thank you Rubel, your solution worked for me. I changed some few things.